# Screen Shortcuts Not Working In Terminal

Tags: command-line, server, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, gnu-screen

I have screen installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 server but when trying to press down on the keys "Ctrl + a + v" or any commands with "Ctrl+a" it doesn't bother to do anything when I am connected to the server with the terminal. I can create sessions with commands but I would prefer to create them using shortcuts. I have already created a session and it works fine, here is the output.

```
There is a screen on:
16245.minecraft (10/01/16 08:50:27) (Detached)
```

And when typing in "screen" I do get put into the licensing page so I have installed it. .

I am currently using the shortcuts in this guide.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server

Answer (score 1):

if you want to attach to the screen: *screen -x 16245.minecraft*
if you want to detach, press ctrl+alt+d (ctrl+a+d sometimes....)
and if you want to create a new screen just type: *screen*

and if you want to create a shortcut for the screen. you could create a .run or .sh file :D
*#!/bin/bash*
*screen -x 16245.minecraft*

after you save this as xyz.run (or .sh) you need to give permission to the user to run
*chmod -x xyz.run*

and then you can attach to the screen just by writeing ./xyz (if not work: ./xyz.run)

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server. This guide shows examples of the shortcuts I am using that won't work on my server. I'm not really looking to create files, I just want to fix the problem on why my shortcuts aren't working